# How to reference variables in a message body of an e-mail alert in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I would like to reference predefined variables, or those defined in templating section of dashboard, to customize alert message, but nothing I tried seems to work. Is it supported at all?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the fact that nobody answered, most probably this is not supported yet in Grafana. However, in my particular case, as the values of variables are known and can be fixed at deploy time (I basically just wanted to notify from which environment comes notification, test or prod), the issue can be solved by using ansible variables in inventory files and fix the message in grafana, at deploy time. But in other cases, this is not sufficient and implementation within Grafana is required.